# Raspberry Pi3, R307 Fingerprint Sensor, UART connection not functioning.

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, uart, fingerprint

I have been trying to connect my raspberry Pi 3 to the R307 Fingerprint Sensor module using UART. I do not want to connect it through a USB and am not using a TTL converter. (And would like to avoid it too.)
I am not able to establish a successful connection between my Pi and the fingerprint sensor module.
I know it is getting connected on port /dev/ttyS0.
I have baudrate set at 57600 (however, I have tried other variations as well).
When I send in some command to execute, it just gives me gibberish results back and ends with: exception, unknown error 0x21.
I am using the library at: https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any more information about my setup is required please ask and I would try to provide them to the best of my knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you powering this sensor module?  Have you measured the voltages of your *"TTL UART"* interfaces"?  Regardless, your question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I have the module powered by the Raspberry Pi from the 5v output. When I check the TTL UART connection, I have on TX - 3.2v and on RX have 4.4v. I do not know where I can post this to get better help. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You have *two* UARTS, one on each end of the serial link.  Measure voltages on both ends.  Is that a stray hyphen or a negative voltage?  The RPi voltages should be only 0 to 3.3V.  Looks like this sensor module outputs more than 3.3V logic levels, and therefore is incompatible with the RPI.  You will need to use level shifters.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust. That is a hyphen and not for negative volts. I would try to measure the other end as well. I would also try with a level shifter and see if that helps. Thanks again.